# UIBarButtonItemの自作した画像の画質について

Tags: objective-c, xcode

現在UIToolbarのUIBarbuttonItemに自分で作った画像を使っているのですが、iOSシュミレータや実機でRunすると画像がぼやけたような感じに画質が下がってしまいます。

自作した画像は画像はIllustratorで50×50pixelsの円形のものです。

どのようにしたら自分で作った画像を綺麗に表示できるでしょうか。

Stackoverflowでするのに場違いな質問だったら申し訳ありません。
どなたかわかる人がいましたらご教授願います。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 自作した画像は画像はIllustratorで50×50pixelsの円形のものです。

50×50ピクセルでも、TabBar Itemにするには、まだ大きいのではありませんか？46×46ピクセル以下で作成してみては？

Illustratorで製作ということは、もとはドローデータですか？ならば、PDF形式で書き出して、それをTabBar ItemのImageにしましょう。
下図は、XcodeのTabbed Applicationテンプレートに付属している、「second」イメージです。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

`second.pdf`というPDF形式のファイルであることがわかります。
ドローデータは、解像度に依存せず、サイズを変えても画質が一定というのは、ご存知のとおりです。

もうすこし説明を追加します。

PDF書類をImageに追加するには、**Images.xcassets**に追加します。その手順を示します。

1. Images.xcassetsのメインエディタ上を右クリックして、プルダウンメニューから「New Image Set」を選択。セットの名称を任意のものに変更。
2. 新規のイメージセットを選択して、Attributes Inspectorの「Scale Factor」を「Single Vector」にする。
3. メインエディタに、PDFファイルをドロップ。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

これで、`TabBarItem`のイメージにすることができます。

※Images.xcassetsをいじってみると、お気づきになると思います。これを利用すると、ビットマップデータでも、異なる解像度のファイルを複数（2個でじゅうぶんでしょう）用意して、デバイス（Retinaディスプレイと非Retina）によって自動切り替えできそうな予感がしますね。

Comment: pdfの画像をBarButtonItemに使うことは可能なんでしょうか...ファイルに入れても、Attributes Inspectorのimageの選択肢に表示されません。

Comment: @h_got 問題解決の入り口までエスコートすればいいのかなと思いましたが、そうではなさそうなので、回答を増補しました。ご覧ください。

Comment: 丁寧に画像追加の最初から教えていただきありがとうございました。無事pdf画像を表示でき画質も問題なくなりました。ありがとうございます。